# numpy.insert troubles

Tags: python, insert, numpy

I am trying to insert `nan`s at certain indices.

```
import numpy
z = numpy.array([1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 0., 7., 8., 9.])
a = z[z!=0]
# Some processing magic happens to a but stays the same shape
b = numpy.argwhere(z == 0).flatten()
c = numpy.insert(a, b, numpy.nan)
```

I would like the result to be:

```
[1, 1, nan, nan, nan, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, nan, 7, 8, 9]
```

but am getting:

```
[1, 1, nan, 2, nan, 3, nan, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, nan]
```

Is there a way to achieve this with `numpy.insert` or another built-in command, and if not, what is a good clean workaround? The list of indices will always be ascending, never have duplicates, but may have gaps like the example.

EDIT Sorry for the confusion while I edited my question.

Comment: I don't quite follow the logic behind your first example (the desired behaviour). Could you explain it?

Comment: For example, `a` is generated from `a = z[z!=0]`; `a` then changes through some processing, and now I need to insert `nan`s where there were originally zeros. The indices are easy to grab using `b = numpy.argwhere(z == 0)`.

Comment: But how does the final `nan` end up at position `10`?

Comment: Why no NaN in the first position?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion as I edited the question. Everybody be cool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will do it:

```
numpy.insert(a, b-numpy.arange(len(b)), numpy.nan)
```

Here is a complete `ipython` session with your example:

```
In [87]: import numpy

In [88]: z = numpy.array([1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 0., 7., 8., 9.])

In [89]: a = z[z!=0]

In [90]: b = numpy.argwhere(z == 0).flatten()

In [91]: c = numpy.insert(a, b, numpy.nan)

In [92]: numpy.insert(a, b - numpy.arange(len(b)), numpy.nan)
Out[92]: 
array([  1.,   1.,  NaN,  NaN,  NaN,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,  NaN,
         7.,   8.,   9.])
```

As you can see, the `NaNs` appear exactly where the zeroes used to be in `z`.

Comment: This can also be achieved with `z[z == 0] = np.nan`.

Comment: @larsmans: My understanding of the question is that we no longer have `z`; we have to reconstruct it from `a` and `b` (since `a` is the result of a transformation of `z`'s elements).

Comment: Excellent. That `b-numpy.arange(len(b))` is what I was missing. Thanks.